# What is the `file` URI scheme in Puppet?

Tags: file, puppet, uri-scheme

[The documentation for the `source` attribute for the `file` resource type](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#file-attribute-source) says:

> The available URI schemes are `puppet` and `file`. `puppet` URIs will ...

It then explains the `puppet` URI scheme, but doesn't say anything about the `file` URI scheme. What is it? What does it mean to assign `"file://foo/bar/baz"` to the `source` attribute on a `file` resource?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme

Comment: @Boann okay, but how is it being interpreted by Puppet? For instance, how are relative paths resolved? And what filesystem does it refer to?

Comment: @Boann for instance, if I reference `"file://foo/bar"` in the file `default.pp`, where there is a file `foo/bar` relative to my `default.pp`, I expect Puppet to find that file, but it doesn't.

Comment: ‎@jameshfisher I don't know anything about puppet, but file URIs are always absolute by definition. You might try `file:///./foo/bar`, but it's not strictly valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file path is always absolute. It refers to a file on the system that runs the catalog. This is the `agent` system, or a machine on which you invoke `puppet apply`.

```
file {
    '/etc/motd':
        source => "file:///media/shared-storage0/motd/${fqdn}.motd";
}
```

For example, the above resource will make the agent sync motd contents and file metadata from a shared storage.

You can omit the `file://` and just use the full path as the source.

```
source => "/media/shared-storage0/motd/${fqdn}.motd";
```

Comment: Ah. So `file:///foo` is completely equivalent to just `/foo`? That settles that. Thanks.